# What YouTube API key to send along with API requests from Apache Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, rest, http, youtube-api, http-referer

YouTube API gives two possible API keys:

- For server applications.
- For browser applications.

I guess *browser application* is the right one when integrating YouTube API into an Apache Cordova application since it's a browser app after all.

The issue here is Apache Cordova won't perform requests with my domain referer and this means that it won't fit YouTube API referer's white list configured on my Google Developers Console.

AFAIK, it's not possible to force a referer in an Apache Cordova app without modifying each platform-specific code, and I'm not sure how I would need to handle this scenario.

My first idea is that my own RESTful API could proxy YouTube one and operate with it from the server-side and this would allow me to use *server applications* approach.

**Am I missing something and there's an alternate approach?**.

*BTW, I believe maybe server application approach might work better because I would centralize the YouTube API key storage and if I need to change it I wouldn't need to force everyone to download a newest version of my mobile app*.

Answer (score 1):

a lighter approach to a server application could be to have your server-side app provide the cordova app with a key upon request. that way the key is not hardcoded in the app (and you can switch keys or even "loadbalance" between keys on your server), but you don't have to worry about the proxying-part either?

frank

Comment: Uhm, but I want to distribute my app like a native one. I mean, I don't want to open the app from internet, but just consume my RESTful API from the local files..

Comment: but your local app will communicate the web, i guess? my point is that you can have your local app contact a remote server app (which you'll have to provide, off course) to get an API key at run-time, avoiding to have to hardcode the key in your app.

Comment: Ah, I see... Well, but at the end of the day, wouldn't be preferable to proxy YouTube requests so I don't need to share my API key at all?

Comment: I mean... At the end of the day, proxying is so easy, and I can avoid, for example, users require to restart the app to get an updated api key if their one has been discarded for some reason (who knows)

Comment: well, proxying will make the app slower, as the vastly YT's api is bound to be faster then a single instance of your proxying app? regarding having to restart the app; i'd cache the key for x hours and then refetch it really, so no restarts would be needed?

Comment: I'll think about this approach, I'm not going to discard at all. You're right that using your approach I wouldn't need to handle YouTube traffic on my app.

Answer (score 0):

I've opted-in to proxy requests to YouTube API using my own RESTful platform.

In summary, I perform a request to a resource URI of some of my own RESTful services and then I do the actual request to YouTube, and once this last one has finished, I return the result to the Cordova app.

I've found this approach has security in mind as I don't need to share my API key with client applications and, if I need to generate a new API key to enhance my security overtime, Cordova app won't cry.